# Installing Powershell v4 on Windows 2012 (NOT 2012R2)

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-update

Windows 2012R2 comes with PS4, but 2012 generic (v6.2 Build 9200) comes with v3. 

There seems to be no installer for 2012. When I attempt to download the installer from [The official MS download site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx) it gives me the options for Windows 8 and WinNt 6.1 (32 and 64)


[image: Download options]


If I try to use the 64bit installer for 6.1, I get an error...


[image: The certificate for the signer of the message is invalid]
The web says this is because it is not a compatible installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download and install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 and Windows Management Framework (WMF) 4.0
Source: http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/windows-powershell-40-released-windows-7-windows-2008-r2-and-windows-server-2012

Comment: Thanks! For other's reference, the download's page no longer lists the download as applicable to 2012. But it does work. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx  Select ```Windows8-RT-KBXXXXXXX-x64.msu```